# Should Bing Maps api keys be kept secret?

Tags: bing-maps, api-key

I need to get the coordinates from the browser and get the address of those coordinates. For that I can use the Bing Maps Location api (https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/*long*,*lat*?c=fi&o=json&key=*myapikey*).

How secret should I keep this key?

When embedding Bing Maps you also need a key that would be seen in the browser. Not sure how that key compares to the Locations api.

- Should I create a separate key for those calls?
- Can I do the api calls from javascript which would expose the key?

  - The alternative being that the frontend does a backend call with the coordinates and the backend is calling the Maps api.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you should keep your key private as anyone who gets the key can make transactions which would be billed to you. In practice this has not been a huge issue and it's easy to block a key and get a new one if this occurs. If you want to be more secure, keeping the key server-side and routing your client calls through the server will protect it. You can also generate a session key from your API key on the server when the page is first rendered and send that to the client. A session key works like a normal key, but has a short expiration time, so there's no danger of it leaking and being used by someone else.